# How to connect to redis through ssh tunnel in Go?

Tags: go, ssh, redis

I'm trying to see if its possible to do an ssh tunnel with redis in go. I'm using the redigo library.

Through command line I typically do something like:

`ssh user@host -p port`

then redis-cli -h redisHost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [network dial](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#DialNetDial) function like this with [Redigo](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis):

```
func dial(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        user := "user"
        password := "password"
        sshAddr := "example.com:22"
        redisAddr := ":6379"
        config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
            User: user,
            Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
                ssh.Password(passord),
            },
        }
        netConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", sshAddr)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        clientConn, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(netConn, sshAddr, config)
        if err != nil {
            netConn.Close()
            return nil, err
        }
        client := ssh.NewClient(clientConn, chans, reqs)
        conn, err := client.Dial("tcp", redisAddr)
        if err != nil {
            client.Close()
            return nil, err
        }
        conn, nil
}
```

If the application creates multiple connections to the server, then create `client` once and reuse on each dial.

The code above is uncompiled and untested.